# How to override print in Forms.WebBrowser

Tags: c#, printing, webbrowser-control

The WebBrowser class in System.Windows.Forms does not handle the `DrawtoBitmap` method correctly as stated on msdn.

I wish to override the `OnPrint` method and perform my own drawing code.

I have tried overriding the `OnPrint(PrintEventArgs e)` method in the WebBrowser class and the code is called, but printing does not change.

I have also tried capturing the `WM_PRINT` method (0x317) and then creating my own Graphics from the message handle. I have tried Using NativeMethods such as `BeginPaint`, `SelectObject` and `EndPaint`. Again the code is called but the printing does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `WndProc(ref Message m)` method.

```
if (m.Msg == 0x317 || m.Msg == 0x318) //WM_PRINT, WM_PRINTCLIENT
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(m.WParam))
    {
        //Draw here
    }
}
```